# Add Custom Filter to Admin User list

Tags: users, filters

What is the correct way to add a custom filter (a dropdown box in this case) to the admin user list (wp-admin/users.php)?

There are no filters or actions that I see to hook into that would allow me to output a select box.

I know I can inject it via javascript, but I'm hoping there's a way to do it on the PHP side.

I am planning on using the results of that filter int as outlined here:
[How to search all user meta from users.php in the admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5811/)

Comment: Looked at the code...you're right...there's no actions or filters in the whole process of generating that table view. The only one is for the role links (the little ones top left).

Comment: Maybe there is some overarching filter that passes in the entire page output and I can add it via regexp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found a potential way (with WP3.1), but it's a bit more involved than using filters:

Since WP3.1 now uses the `WP_List_Class` to generate the admin pages, you can create your own `My_User_List_Table` class, inheriting from `WP_Users_List_Table` and in that class override the `extra_tablenav()` method. In your own method you duplicate the code from `WP_Users_List_Table::extra_tablenav()` and add your own stuff.

Then you create a duplicate of `wp-admin/users.php`, modify it to use your class instead and modify the users menu entry in the admin navigation to call your duplicate instead of `wp-admin/users.php`. I'm not sure if WP3.1 now comes with easier methods to do that then the hacky solutions necessary for WP3.0.

Unfortunately, all this new WP_List_Class stuff comes without good action or filter hooks, it would have been so easy had they added an `apply_filters()` call to `_get_list_table()`. Grmpf.

Comment: You should never advise to change core files, man. That's just wrong...